How to solve for a value in a log
I have a formula:
Weight=onerepmax*(0.488 + 0.538 * ln(-0.075*reps))
And I need to solve for reps given a onerepmax and a weight.
I got as far as:
ln(-0.075*reps) = ((weight/(onerepmax)) - 0.488)/0.538 
But I am not sure how I can move the reps out of the log base e function.

In general,
$$
\ln(x) = y \iff x = e^y
$$
where $e \approx 2.718$ is Euler's constant (on the assumption you are using the base-$e$ logarithm). Hence, raise both sides to the power of $e$ to get
$$
-0.075 \cdot \text{reps} = \exp \left( \frac{ \frac{\text{weight}}{\text{one_rep_max}} - 0.488}{0.538} \right)
$$
where
$$
\exp z := e^z
$$
for notational pleasantry.
You can then continuing solving/simplifying from here.
